# hive shell is not working

Tags: hive, hql, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

when i try to access the hive shell, it is showing some error logs. i am using CDH version 5.12.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getAuthorizationMode(SessionState.java:1679)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.isAuthorizationModeV2(SessionState.java:1690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.processors.CommandUtil.authorizeCommand(CommandUtil.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.processors.AddResourceProcessor.run(AddResourceProcessor.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processInitFiles(CliDriver.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
    ... 45 more
)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 42 more
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure in your hive-site.xml has below configuration,

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore_db? 
      createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false
    </value>
</property
```